# Hessian in SAS?

Tags: sas, glm, logistic-regression, sas-iml, hessian-matrix

Is there any way to get the Hessian matrix in the proc logistic in SAS? Or which will be an option to calculated it taking from departure the proc logsitic?

I have been reading the function documentation but cannot see that there is a way to include it in the output tables.

Comment: Adding [tag:SAS-iml] in case one of the iml folks knows the answer.  You might want to look at [this SAS newsgroup question](http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.sas/hessian-and-scores-in-the-logistic-proc/661329) as it looks like it might not be directly obtainable, but they have some instructions for how to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks for the tag suggestion. I saw the link you post it before, but my code is already time consuming (around 2-3 hours since it estimates more than 1000 models and the data set is 'big') so I want to keep it as simple as possible. I cannot beleive SAS does not output the hessian matrix in the logistic procedure! I have done this in matlab and R before.

Comment: Post the question at communities.sas.com and someone from SAS can respond. If there isn't a way, you can also add it as an idea on that site.

Comment: You also should consider trying `ods trace on;` before the procedure and checking to see if it is available - I am not familiar with it specifically but a lot of hidden data is available that way.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will look into it. However, I missed the point that the covariance matrix of the parater estimates (which is an output in proc logistic) is calculated from the hessian matrix. So can get a good estimate of the hessian by going that way!

Comment: excelent.... my sas version does not contain the INV() function :(

Comment: I came across with this [link](http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2010/CC/CC15.pdf) It has some usefull macros :) I just hope the macro is not time consuming and my code performance wont be impact.

Comment: Maybe this is useful? http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/67517/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_nlpsolver_details09.htm

Answer (score 1):

I scoured the SAS blogs and may have found a way you can estimate it using proc nlp.

```
data t1;
do i = 1 to 500;
x=rannor(3478);
y=1+2*x>rannor(3478);
output;
end;
run;

proc logistic data=t1 outest=parm covout desc;
model y=x/link=probit;
score data=t1 out=t2;
run;

proc nlp data=t1 outest=t2 PHESSIAN;
parms a=0, b=0 ;
max ll;
xbeta = a + b * x;
if y=1 then p=probnorm(xbeta);
else if y=0 then p=1-probnorm(xbeta);
ll=LOG(p);
run;

proc print data=parm(where=(_TYPE_='COV')); run;

*calculation covariance from hessian in above;
proc iml;

HESSIAN={ -143.2141617 64.771275623,
64.771275623 -64.13869603
};
HESSIAN_inv_neg=-inv(HESSIAN);
print HESSIAN ;
print HESSIAN_inv_neg;
quit;
```

Hope this helps.

Original answer posted here: http://comp.soft-sys.sas.narkive.com/nXdobtA5/hessian-and-scores-in-the-logistic-proc